# mat select not in certain position

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular5, angular-material-5

i have a problem, when i add a picture in my page. The selected option like in this picture
[image]

but if i remove the image the result is normal like no problems[image]

Here is my code

.html

```
<div class="container">
    <img class="panjang" src="assets/imgs/cover_pln.png">
  </div>
<mat-tab-group mat-stretch-tabs color="accent">
  <mat-tab label="One" color="accent" >
    <br>
    <br> 
    <form class="example-form">
      <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
        <input matInput placeholder="Test">
        <mat-hint>Test</mat-hint>
      </mat-form-field>
      <br>
      <br> 
      <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
        <input matInput placeholder="Test">
        <mat-hint>Test</mat-hint>
      </mat-form-field>
      <br>
      <br> 
      <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
        <input matInput placeholder="Test">
        <mat-hint>Test</mat-hint>
      </mat-form-field>
    </form>
  </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Two" color="accent">
      <br>
      <br>
      <form class="example-form">
        <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
          <input matInput placeholder="Test">
          <mat-hint>Test</mat-hint>
        </mat-form-field>
        <br>
        <br>
        <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
          <input matInput placeholder="No.Ponsel">
          <mat-hint>Test</mat-hint>
        </mat-form-field>
        <br>
        <br>
        <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
          <mat-select [(value)]="selected" placeholder="Test">
            <mat-option >Test</mat-option>
            <mat-option >Test</mat-option>
            <mat-option >Test</mat-option>
            <mat-option >Test</mat-option>
            <mat-option >Test</mat-option>
            <mat-option >Test</mat-option>
          </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
        <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
          <input matInput placeholder="Test">
          <mat-hint>Test</mat-hint>
        </mat-form-field>
      </form>
  </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

.css

```
.mat-tab-label {
        background-color: transparent;
        color: #5c5c5c;
        font-weight: 700;
    }

/* Styles for the active tab label */
.mat-tab-label.mat-tab-label-active {
    background-color: transparent;
    color: #448AFF;
    font-weight: 700;
}
.example-form {
    min-width: 50%;
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.example-full-width {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top:1%;
}
.mat-select{
    margin-top: 1%;
    position: bottom;
}
.panjang{
    width:75%;
}
.container{
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left:1%;
    margin-right:1%;
}
```

i'm using angular 5 material. Is there any way to override the default position of select option in angular material? or is there any other solution of this problem.Thank you

The Demo  :https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-select2-tjeqfz?file=app/select-hint-error-example.html
thanks to Yerkon

Comment: I can't reproduce this behaviour, https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-select2-u4okcb

Comment: try this @Yerkon https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-select2-tjeqfz?file=app/select-hint-error-example.html

Comment: i forgot to add value @Yerkon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
          <mat-select [(value)]="selected" placeholder="Test">
            <mat-option >Test</mat-option>
            <mat-option >Test</mat-option>
            <mat-option >Test</mat-option>
            <mat-option >Test</mat-option>
            <mat-option >Test</mat-option>
            <mat-option >Test</mat-option>
          </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
```

In your HTML code which i have reflected above, remove class `example-full-width` which has 100% width.

Answer (score 4):

The position of the select's option is calculated dynamically by Material itself. 
The positioned element has class `cdk-overlay-pane` and you can add your own specific css class when creating instance of the select as mentioned in the documentation https://material.angular.io/cdk/overlay/api#OverlayConfig

If you are using template, then try to add custom css class to the template and play with the styles to achieve desired effect.

But keep in mind, that the position is calculated dynamically and depends on available space, how close is the `select` to the top or bottom of the screen etc.

Answer (score 1):

Material select has private method [_calculateOverlayOffsetY](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/7857b92c47630478a34050d07f449809183900bc/src/lib/select/select.ts#L1086):

> /**    * Calculates the y-offset of the select's overlay panel in
>   relation to the    * top start corner of the trigger. It has to be
>   adjusted in order for the    * selected option to be aligned over the
>   trigger when the panel opens.    */

You can't override it, it's `private`. I think you should open `issue` on `Angular material` github or maybe it's already opened. 
But as you can see, when you resize the window or do scrolling, dialog recalculates it's position.